# Getting a ValueError in tensorflow saying that my shapes are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Error:

```
return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits)
    C:\Users\selvaa\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4619 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\selvaa\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1128 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 151) are incompatible
```

My model:

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

x = x/255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3,3), input_shape=(128,128,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(302, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(151, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

I'm trying to train a model to identify different pokemon, I have two pictures of each 151 pokemon for my datasets (correctly labeled and all). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is what happens when I print x.shape and y.shape:

```
(301, 128, 128, 3) (301,)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the loss [`tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy), as shown in the code example below.

The loss function `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossEntropy` accepts reference labels in the shape `(n_samples,)` and predicted labels in the shape `(n_samples, n_classes)`, which would work for your data. You cannot use `categorical_crossentropy` because that expects your labels to be one-hot encoded (see bottom of answer).

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

x = x / 255.0

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(3, (3,3), input_shape=(128,128,3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(302, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(151, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
    optimizer='adam', 
    metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, batch_size=32, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)
```

---

Another solution is to one-hot encode your labels prior to training, for example using the function [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot). If you use this approach, then you can use `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thanks! The SparseCategoricalCrossentropy worked, however, I still had a problem as it said that I couldn't convert str to float. So I changed all the labels to the pokemon number, which is a bit annoying, but it works!

Comment: Yes you will need to map your pokemon from their string labels to some integer or float. Glad this helped.